# When do we need buffers in C?

Tags: c

I was reading others' code and saw so many people using something like BUFFER_SIZE as a macro. The thing is, many programs could be written without this buffer thing. So when do we need buffer and when not? I mean, why we need a buffer? And how to use it properly?

Comment: Is this even a real question?  Is it about buffers in general, using a macro instead of a magic number, or how to write programs without buffers?  Clarify this to remove my downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From wikipedia:

> a buffer is a region of a physical memory storage used to temporarily hold data while it is being moved from one place to another.

With that being said, I feel there are a few concrete uses of buffers:

- Transforming an asynchronous data source into a synchronous data source:
  This is a big one, and a lot of APIs are built with this mindset.  For example, imagine you're reading a  data source which is inherently prone to failure. Asynchronously you have a stream which can fail at certain times, but you can request the data be read again.  This handling of data is a very low level detail, and you wouldn't want programmers at a high level to have to worry about it.  The solution, write a low level handler which manages the stream and put data in a buffer once it's safely been read in.  For example, you see this use of a buffer in file systems, network protocols, etc...
- Passing large amounts of data around:  If you want to share data between multiple people, you need a temporary place to store data to mediate it between people.
- Copying things / doing destructive manipulations:  If you have a situation where you need to free one pointer and move something around in memory (for whatever reason), you can put the data in a temporary holding place.  One common case is where I'm doing something like destructively manipulating a string: I can't manipulate the original string, I need to make a copy of it, so I don't corrupt the pointer if other people are holding on to it.

Answer (score 0):

A buffer is just a chunk of data, how much you need and when you need it is task dependent. The most common operations involving buffers are File I/O and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it's used to absorb some network jitter.
The reason you can watch a movie smoothly on Youtube is because that your browser first download some data into a buffer, and then play it.